# Implementing Spotify API with React

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I apologize if this is a really basic question, but I am a beginner with a fundamental lack of understanding of how a React app works. Right now I am creating an app which uses Spotify API, including authentication. With React, I want to be able to fetch the data in my components. However, the API does not let me as it is meant to be fetched from 'server side'. My question is, how is the distinction made / how would I go about creating a 'server side' where all I do is authenticate and retrieve data from the api?

Answer (score 1):

React is:

> A JAVASCRIPT LIBRARY FOR BUILDING USER INTERFACES

So it is meant to develop client side of the applications (even though this can be done server side). Therefore would not it be better to use one of existing client side packages to access spotify api, like these ones: [Spotify Web API JS](https://github.com/jmperez/spotify-web-api-js), [Spotify Web API Node](https://github.com/thelinmichael/spotify-web-api-node)

More packages are mentioned in the 
 [spotify web api](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/code-examples/) page, have a look.